# How do I create a post for Disqus from iOS?

Tags: ios, post, comments, disqus

I'm developing an application for a client. This app enables user to read and post comment. Our client website have already used Discus. Now that we can retrieve the comment and display it natively. But we find no way to create a post and send it to Disqus. Does anyone have some experiences with Disqus on iOS ?

Any idea will be much appreciated.

Edit : our client website has an authentication system already and thus we also integrate that system to our app. Every time user post a comment in the app, we'll use his/her authentication information. We don't want user to authenticate again.

Comment: I assume you want their API? http://disqus.com/api/docs/

Comment: But no :(. I have read a lot about it and search a lot. Beside embedded it in the uiwebview, there seems to be no way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the API set up on your server, correct? Then post a request to your server, pass it whatever API keys and credentials you need, and have the server make a post to the Disqus API on behalf of the client.  Basically, build your own iOS API for interfacing with the Disqus API through your server.

Even better though would be to directly interact with the Disqus server by making requests using NSURLRequest/Connection.  For more information on Disqus requests [look here](http://disqus.com/api/docs/requests/).  That would make your app faster and be less error prone, unless you are doing some critical activity on your server, other than just posting and displaying comments.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. YES, we have the API set up on our server. So your idea is I have to invoke the server to post the comment instead. Is it related to something called SSO from Disqus ?

Comment: That's exactly my idea.  However, that is even more complicated than just making direct requests to the Disqus RESTful API. http://disqus.com/api/docs/requests/, which you can POST and GET information from.

Comment: I am still not clear about authentication. If I make direct requests to Disqus, I need to authenticate user with Disqus right ?

Comment: I have gone through SSO process, now I come up with "Bad request" respond. It got me stuck now. I cannot figure out where to go further!

Comment: Thanks again AdamG, after several tries I can successfully post the comment from my iOS app directly to Disqus. It was SSO things that keeps me from succeeded.

Comment: Awesome! Congratulations! :).

Comment: Can we post comment as guest? If yes then which parameters have to be used? And what changes need to be done to API settings?

Comment: @Sudakura: Could you please share details about how to post comments from iOS application? Please sahre iff you have any code snippet. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a great solution which helps  easily integrate Disqus into iOS apps https://github.com/moqod/disqus-ios. Works like a charm out of the box.

Not only you can make posts, but also authorize thru social networks and respond to comments.

Answer (score 0):

@RahuGupta: Sorry if it's too late for a response. I posted comment using SSO, I don't know about posting as guest. But it should be easier.

In my case I post a comment using third party authentication server which means we authenticate users by ourselves. The technique called SSO. You may want to read the documentation about SSO on Disqus.

In case you need code snippet in objective-c :

```
NSMutableDictionary *dico = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dico setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"uniqueId_%@",comment.authorID] forKey:@"id"];
[dico setValue:comment.authorName forKey:@"username"];
[dico setValue:comment.authorEmail forKey:@"email"];


NSString *message = [dico JSONRepresentation];
NSString *message64Based = [DataPost base64String:message];

NSTimeInterval timeStamp = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970];

NSString *secret = DISQUS_API_SECRET;
NSString *api_key = DISQUS_API_PUBLIC;

//comment.threadID will makes the app crashed, because when comment is not fully loaded, it's nil
NSString *threadID = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",comment.threadID];

NSString *commentMessage = [[comment.rawMessage stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];

NSString *host     = @"http://example.com";
NSString *referrer = @"example.com";

NSString *hmac = [self hashedValue:secret andData:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %.0lf",message64Based, timeStamp]];
NSString *remote_auth_s3 = [[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %.0lf", message64Based, hmac, timeStamp] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"=" withString:@"%3D"] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"+"];


NSMutableURLRequest *uploadRequest = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://disqus.com/api/3.0/posts/create.json"] cachePolicy: NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData timeoutInterval: 60.0f];

NSMutableData *postData = (NSMutableData *)[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"_format=json&thread=%@&message=%@&remote_auth=%@&api_key=%@&strict=1", threadID , commentMessage, remote_auth_s3 , api_key] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
[uploadRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[uploadRequest setHTTPBody: postData];
[uploadRequest setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[uploadRequest setValue:referrer forHTTPHeaderField:@"referrer"];
[uploadRequest setValue:host forHTTPHeaderField:@"host"];

[uploadRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

NSHTTPURLResponse *response=nil;
NSError *error = nil;
[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:uploadRequest returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: I need SSO for disqus and I try this your code and does not send a comment. I have all data for send.

Comment: What should we pass as "host" and referrer values

Comment: Could you please explain what "hashedValue" is expected to return, as it's taking secret key along with other data.